# Log postman runner data(cvs) parameters

Tags: javascript, list, logging, postman, postman-collection-runner

I want to log the parameters sent through a cvs file when running the Collection runner. Is this possible? I want retrieve a list of all parameters that failed (over 6000 items being tested).

When i export the test result, i can not see the parameters items that failed. Which I want.

Ive tried to log the response as following:

```
console.log(DRAWING_NO)
```

DRAWING_NO is a global variable set in the environment

test code

```
enter var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

if (jsonData.Drawings === null) {

    pm.test("sample-test-fail", function () {
        throw new Error();
        });

   let drawingno = pm.iterationData.get("DRAWING_NO");
   console.log(drawingno);

} else if (jsonData.Drawings !== null) {


//postman.setEnvironmentVariable("UFID", jsonData.Drawings.Drawing.UFID);

//console.log(jsonData.Drawings.Drawing.length);

pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});



jsonData.Drawings.Drawing.forEach(function (data) {


    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("UFID", data.UFID);
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("INST_TYPE", data.INST_TYPE);
     postman.setEnvironmentVariable("HYD_TYPE", data.HYD_TYPE);


     pm.test("Check Drawing NO for " + data.DRAWING_NO, function(){
        pm.expect(data.DRAWING_NO).not.eql(null);

    });

     pm.test("Check Sales ID for " + data.DRAWING_NO, function(){
        pm.expect(data.SALES_ID).not.eql(null);

});

 pm.test("Check HYD_TYPE for " + data.DRAWING_NO, function(){
    pm.expect(data.HYD_TYPE).not.eql(null);

});
 pm.test("Check INST_TYPE NO for " + data.DRAWING_NO, function(){
    pm.expect(data.INST_TYPE).not.eql(null);

    });

    pm.test("Check Sales Code for " + data.DRAWING_NO, function(){
        pm.expect(data.SALES_CODE).not.eql(null);

    });

    pm.test("Check LIFECYCLE_STATE for " + data.DRAWING_NO, function(){
        pm.expect(data.LIFECYCLE_STATE).eql("RELEASED");

    });

  //pm.test("Check VERSION CODE Code for " + data.DRAWING_NO, function () {
//    pm.expect(data.VERSION_CODE).not.eql(null);

//});

//pm.test("Check DRIVE UNIT for " + data.DRAWING_NO, function () {
//    pm.expect(data.DRIVE_UNIT).not.eql(null);

//});


//pm.test("Check Outlet US for " + data.DRAWING_NO, function () {
//    pm.expect(data.OUTLET_US).not.eql(null);

//});


});

}
```

here

[image]

Comment: Have you tried console.log(data.DRAWING_NO)? What's the conditions of a Failure? Do you have a test in place for this?

Comment: Yes i have tests in place. So if the DRAWING_NO does not exist, output error. Then some other conditions associated with the response to each DRAWING_NO. If any conditions fail, i want to log the DRAWING_NO as a list. 

Basically the Drawing_NO is the primary key and the one im doing the search on, on the API request.

Comment: Can you update the question with the test code? It might give people an idea of how best to log the failed values out for you. This is just a bunch of words at the moment so it's tough to know what's going on.

Comment: Now ive added the test code